# Roman numbers in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

How can I write roman numbers in the program inkscape? Do I have to use the glyph-mode somehow or how is it done? Strangely, manually putting in the Unicode for example for the 'I' , U+2160 does not work and give me an 'I' in the text on my drawings.

Comment: Hi Lucas, welcome to GD.SE! Does this happen only for those ascii characters? Or did you also find others that don't work as expected?

Comment: What do yo mean by *glyph mode?* What happens, if you try to copy and paste the correct character? What happens if you input it diretcly (e.g., via [Compose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key))? Also, do not forget that your font’s Roman 1 may just look like an *I.*

Comment: you mean I should try to copy a roman IV for example from the internet and paste it into inkscape?

Comment: Yes, but be sure that it’s the actual Unicode character, and not just I + V. Here is one: Ⅳ.

Answer (score 1):

I would use whatever glyph finder ships with your OS and copy and paste as @Wrzlprmft suggests.

Inkscape itself has a character/glyph dialogue under `Text -> Glyphs...` but on my (Xubuntu) system I couldn't find any Roman Numerals despite you giving the Unicode for one example.

"Character Map" in my "Accessories" under Xubuntu does show me Roman Numerals and I know that Windows ships with a similar Character Map program.

Comment: Roman numerals should be under *Number Forms* in *Text → Glyphs.*

Comment: Yep, agreed - that's where they are under "Character Map" but they don't appear in the Glyphs menu in Inkscape using the same font choice (Ubuntu).

Comment: For me they do, provided I choose a font that actually contains Roman numerals.

Comment: I've tried this in Inkscape 0.48 on Windows 7 and it does _not_ work. When pasting, I just get a blank space, even if the font has roman numbers (e.g. same font in both the character map and Inkscape). I've encountered similar issues with other glyphs in Inkscape.

Comment: There are various open bug reports relating to Glyph handling, Unicode fonts and copy'n'pasting over on the Inkscape bug tracker.
E.g.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/555557
https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/491995
Might be that there isn't (yet) a definitive answer on all OSes for this.