# What’s the right character for a minus sign?

Tags: typography, typesetting, character

Almost everywhere I see the so called [*hyphen-minus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (Unicode character `U+002D` and HTML symbol `&#45`) used as a minus sign, which is actually the standard [*hyphen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) character (Unicode character `U+2010` and HTML symbol `&#8208;`) as you can see in this example equation:

[image: hyphen(-minus) example as minus sign]

As you can realize, in most fonts the hyphen-minus does not have the optimal width, thickness or position to represent a minus sign and therefore [practicaltypography.com](http://practicaltypography.com) suggests to

> use an [*en dash*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash), which makes an acceptable minus sign in spread­sheets or mathematical expressions.

which looks like this when we follow our example:

[image: en dash example as minus sign]

But in my opinion this is a little bit misleading, because an en dash is also used to indicate spans or differentiation:

[image: en dash span example]

On the other hand there exists a “correct” [*minus sign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) (Unicode character `U+2212` and HTML symbol `&minus;`) for "*everyday speech*" but which is rarely used for some reason:

[image: minus sign used in equation]

I wonder now if a *hyphen(-minus)* sign, *en dash* or a *minus sign* should be used to represent a minus in typographic context.

---

As *@PieBie* and *@Zach Saucier* pointed out there are many use cases out there. But does the type of publication make any *difference*?

I mean why should we not use the same minus character when writing a mathematical equation or indicate a negative vote for a post for instance on this site:

[image: example for minus signs: hyphen(-minus), en dash and minus sign]

---

*As a side note:* I also dont know why no *minus sign* (`U+2212`) but rather a hyphen(-minus) gets displayed when we press the minus key <kbd>-</kbd> on our [numpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad). Why are there two same keys for different characters?

<sup>**Note:** The sans-serif typeface [*Arial*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) was used in the examples.</sup>

Comment: "I wonder now if it is ok to be lazy and use a hyphen(-minus) sign or an en dash as minus" - this is completely opinion based as far as I can tell. Can you please try to rephrase this to make it less opinion based?

Comment: Additionally, could you provide more information on the *type* of publication? Is it a mathematical treatise where the minus sign is going to be used a lot, or is it a promotional flyer where the minus is used to indicate a discount?

Comment: @PieBie: Should this really make a difference? :)

Comment: So you have no real use case in mind, you're just asking for the sake of asking?

Comment: @ZachSaucier: Yes. I am interested in the correct usage in general. :)

Comment: You definitely should not use an an dash, because 5–10 reads “5 to 10” not “5 minus 10.”

Comment: @SimonWhite: Yes as I mentioned in my post that’s what I thought too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## If you want a minus sign, use a minus sign.

That's what it's for, after all.

That being said—unless you are writing for a mathematical publication or in a similar context it probably won't go noticed if you do use a hyphen or dash. I know I have used a hyphen-minus or en-dash countless times in the past.

As you mentioned in your question, there is no key for a minus sign on a keyboard, only a hyphen. For that reason alone, average Joe doesn't use a minus sign, he uses a hyphen (or hyphen-minus).

### A few things to note.

A hyphen or dash will usually have a different vertical alignment to the minus and other mathematical symbols. It often isn't much but if you are using more mathematical symbols than just a minus sign it may be noticeable. If you are going to the trouble of using other correct mathematical symbols then it's not much more effort to use the correct minus sign.

A few examples of dashes and mathematical symbols in different fonts, to illustrate the difference in alignment:

[image]

If no minus sign is available, the en-dash should be closest in design and should be used instead.

#### Keyboard hyphen key

The hyphen key on your keyboard is actually called [hyphen-minus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) because it is intended to be used as the minus sign and for hyphens/dashes. This character is still present in Unicode for compatibility reasons (its character code is U+002D), but Unicode also encodes the hyphen (‐, U+2010) and minus sign (−, U+2212) separately.

I assume no minus sign, or any specific dashes are included in keyboard layouts for a number of reasons. Firstly historical—it saved space on typewriter and early computer keyboard keys. Secondly, it wouldn't really make sense—how would you differentiate the various dashes, hyphen and minus sign? The length would be hardly noticeable in isolation and adding *en*, *em* etc would probably confuse anyone not versed in typographical terms.

With regards to your note on the [numpad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad), I'm not sure why a minus sign isn't used. It seems like it should be. It may be for technical reasons. I'm not familiar with the engineering of a keyboard but maybe both hyphen(-minus) keys use (or historically did) the same circuitry. It may also simply be not to cause confusion, with two identical looking keys outputting different characters.

**In short—If you are writing mathemtical formulae, use the correct symbol. Otherwise you can probably get away with a hyphen-minus or an en-dash (but if you're going to the trouble of using an en-dash, just use a minus sign!).**

---

### Some Related Reading

- [**Hyphen, minus, en-dash, and em-dash: difference and usage in English**](https://jakubmarian.com/hyphen-minus-en-dash-and-em-dash-difference-and-usage-in-english/)
- [**FontShop.com Blog - Hyphen, En Dash, Em Dash, Minus**](http://blog.fontshop.com/2013/07/11/hyphen-en-dash-em-dash-minus/)

Comment: Fun fact: recently this caused a *massive* row on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317907/negative-question-scores-should-be-prefixed-with-a-−-minus-sign-instead-of-a). Spoiler Alert: negative votes on the entire Stack Exchange sites are *not* indicated by a proper minus. (I did not notice until this was pointed out. Now it bugs me immensely )

Comment: That discussion is highly entertaining! I completely agree it *should* be a minus sign and I would much prefer if it was, but I'm not surprised at all—I'm more surprised when I do see a proper minus sign in any web design, or anything digital that isn't design/typography/academic related for that matter.

Comment: People do not agree on this point. Full Stop. When I suggested that one should use roman numerals because of the [semantics](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49265/why-should-i-ever-use-unicode-s-special-characters-for-roman-numerals/49293#49293) not all people agree. Basically its a mess everybody uses hypen as minus everywhere even code that has a lot of expression uses the wrong character. There is not a easy way out of this question. Purist would like to use you know a actual minus but the pragmatics can not concede because it would mean a ton of documents to fix.

Comment: I agree. It is a mess and there isn't really a way out of the issue. The roman numerals is basically the same argument.

Comment: Cursed be the person who made the design of hyphenminus on the keyboard. Why oh why, can not the operators on the numeric keypad give proper mathematical symbols.

Comment: @joojaa - When the PC keyboard was invented ... Unicode didn't exist.  In fact, "typography" didn't exist either except in offline batch-mode programs (e.g., TeX precursors) that produced printed output on printers that cost lotsa $$$. If you want to curse someone involved with keyboard design then curse the person who decided that function keys should be the _top row_ of the keyboard, instead of nicely arranged in a 2x6 box on the left side, where God intended them to be (and where they were originally, and could be touch-typed easily).

Comment: @davidbak yes I understand that it was a typewriter. Still thats what unintended consequences of design looks like.

Comment: The 1980s Macintosh included the hyphen, en-dash, and em-dash on its standard US keyboard layout as hyphen, option+hyphen, and option-shift-hyphen, and I used them all the time when writing text documents.  I'm not sure why the US layout for the PC has never bothered to include most of the useful characters that were so easily available on the 1980s Macintosh.

Comment: On Linux (X Window System), there is an option called "Unicode additions", which changes the operators on the numeric keypad to U+2215 DIVISION SLASH, U+22C5 DOT OPERATOR, U+2212 MINUS SIGN; U+002B PLUS SIGN remains.

Comment: On some layouts you can also get the en-dash with AltGr+- and the em-dash with Shift+AltGr+-.