# Why is the numpad on a keyboard not designed to print typographically correct symbols?

Tags: history, hardware, character

As Wikipedia states, the [*numeric keypad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_keypad), *number pad* or short *numpad*

> provides calculator-style efficiency for entering numbers. The numpad’s keys are digits from <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd>, addition (<kbd>+</kbd>), subtraction (<kbd>−</kbd>), multiplication (<kbd>×</kbd>) and division (<kbd>÷</kbd>) symbols, …

I wonder now why for instance when we press the <kbd>−</kbd> key on our numpad a [*hyphen-minus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus) (Unicode character `U+002D` and HTML symbol `&#45`) gets displayed rather than the “correct” [*minus sign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) (Unicode character `U+2212` and HTML symbol `&minus;`).

The same thing applies also to the <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>×</kbd> and <kbd>÷</kbd> keys;

- the <kbd>+</kbd> yields not a [full-width plus (`＋`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0b/index.htm), but rather a standard `+` sign,
- the <kbd>×</kbd> prints an [asterisk (`*`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) and no [multiplication sign (`×`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign)
- and the <kbd>÷</kbd> displays a [slash (`/`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29) rather than the suspected [obelus (÷)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelus)

… although all of this symbols are shown on the keyboard keys as you can see in the following *German computer keyboard* illustration from [commons.wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Computer_keyboard_German.svg):

[image: German computer keyboard from commons.wikimedia.org]

Is there any technical reason for this behavior – as @CAI mentions in his [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/68679/46556) about the correct minus sign – or a is this only because of historical reason?

Comment: Does the same apply to the `+` `×` & `÷` keys? They are correct aren't they?

Comment: Yes as I said; the [+] yields no full-width plus (＋), the [×] an asterisk (*) and no multiplication sign (×) and the [÷] a slash (/) rather than an obelus (÷) although this symbols are printed on the keys :)

Comment: Ah ok, that I didn't realise! (I don't have a numpad on my keyboard) and you edited that in to the post after my comment ;)

Comment: My keyboard has this on the numpad keys: - * / +, so to me they get 'printed' correctly.

Comment: @PieBie: I added an example image… ;)

Comment: My keyboard really has  a slash and an asterisk on it, really really

Comment: Yah I know, most of the keyboards are designed like yours – but there are some exceptions … :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Historical reasons only – plus a side dish of "backward compatibility".

The original PC keyboards were very much 'typewriter-like'. Also, in the original ASCII set there *were* no 'fullwidth plus', 'minus', and 'multiply' symbols. The common MS-DOS 'extended ASCII' set contained a proper 'divide' – but only in certain codepages. (Only a guess, but it can be assumed the asterisk was chosen for 'multiplication' rather than <kbd>×</kbd> because it would look too close to the lowercase character <kbd>x</kbd>.)

Since lots of computers were used for administrative purposes only, the calculator-like keypad addition appeared later on. Initially it doubled for use with the arrow, page up/down, and home/end keys; later on, these in turn appeared as *extra* extra keys. The labeling on the keypad keys duplicated those of calculators at that time, but the *character* they typed had to be the same as the original ones used, for compatibility with existing software *and* for keyboards without the extra keys.

The key caps reflect what the *keys* insert into programs to do the *function* they describe. It’s quite similar to pressing a key labelled "Backspace" and expecting that literal text to turn up.

I know of no software at all that allows to use the Unicode character `×` for multiplication. The same goes for the Unicode characters Mathematical Minus and Divide (come to think of it, neither do other function/characters such as the Square glyph "<sup>2</sup>" – entering "5<sup>2</sup>" into a calculator does not make it show "25" – and the Square Root character).

It’s not the only peculiarity of standard keyboards. Most have All Caps letters printed on the keys, but all of the computers I know *start up in lowercase mode*, and it takes an extra key (Shift) or software mode (Caps Lock) to actually enter uppercase characters.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very interesting answer  ;) You are right the keys are labeled with caps, but default they print a lowercase character. On the other hand I think it would be a nice option to enter the typographical correct signs by pressing [ALT] + [*Some numpad operator*] … :)

Comment: @elegent: I know it's possible on Windows to edit your own keyboard, which would make it 'system wide'. And of course some software has shortcuts built in for specific typographic refinements (such as InDesign, which offers immediate access to curly quotes). But it's worth remembering such refinements may not work in 'general' software - i.e., Calculator expects a hyphen, not a U+2212 minus.